# Cond(PA)=Cond(A)

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-norms, condition-number

I want to proof the following equation. A is a nxn regular matrix and P a permutation Matrix

$$cond_2(PA)=cond_2(A)$$

So the spectral norm of $||P||=1$

so $cond(PA)=||PA|| \cdot ||(PA)^{-1}||$

I tried to show that $||A||\leq||PA||\leq||A||$
Can I do the same with $||(PA)^{-1}||$

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are considering the changes of the euclidean norm and its operator norm under an orthogonal transformation. But orthogonal transformations are exactly those that leave this norm invariant...

Comment: Thanks, I know that it has to be true but is there a possibility, to show it, with the definition of the cond:

$cond(A)=||A|| \cdot ||A^{-1}||$ and $cond(PA)=||PA|| \cdot ||(PA)^{-1}||$

Comment: You have for any orthogonal $Q$ that $\|QA\|_{2,op}=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|QAx\|_2=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2=\|A\|_{2,op}$ and similarly $\|(QA)^{-1}\|_{2,op}=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|A^{-1}Q^tx\|_2=\sup_{\|y\|_2=1}\|A^{-1}y\|_2=\|A^{-1}\|_{2,op}$. This only works this nicely for the euclidean norm.